# Python - How to Combine Two Dictionaries by Keys

Tags: python, dictionary, union, python-itertools

I have two dicts:

```
A={'a':{"total":5,"all":[100,101]},'b':{"total":10,"all":[200,201]}}
B={'a':{"q1":"a","q2":"aa"},'b':{"q1":"b"},'c':{"q1":"c","q2":"ccc"}}
```

I combine all the values in the dicts based on their keys (a,b,c) as follows:

```
import collections
super_dict = collections.defaultdict(set)
for k, v in chain(A.items(), B.items()):
    #related_datasets = v.get("all")
    #total_downloads = v.get("total")
    #query_1 = v.get("q1")
    #query_2 = v.get("q2")
    super_dict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

This resulted in (super_dict):

```
defaultdict(set,
            {'a': [{'all': [100, 101], 'total': 5}, {'q1': 'a', 'q2': 'aa'}],
             'b': [{'all': [200, 201], 'total': 10}, {'q1': 'b'}],
             'c': [{'q1': 'c', 'q2': 'ccc'}]})
```

However, I want to produce a super_dict as follows:

```
{'a': {'all': [100, 101], 'q1': 'a', 'q2': 'aa', 'total': 5},
 'b': {'all': [200, 201], 'q1': 'b', 'total': 10},
 'c': {'q1': 'c', 'q2': 'ccc'}}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

ok i found the solution:

```
import collections
super_dict = {}
for k, v in chain(A.items(), B.items()):
    related_datasets = v.get("all")
    total_downloads = v.get("total")
    query_1 = v.get("q1")
    query_2 = v.get("q2")
    vkeys = v.keys()
    if k in super_dict.keys():
        super_dict[k].update(v)
    else:
        super_dict[k]= v
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close:

```
A={'a':{"total":5,"all":[100,101]},'b':{"total":10,"all":[200,201]}}
B={'a':{"q1":"a","q2":"aa"},'b':{"q1":"b"},'c':{"q1":"c","q2":"ccc"}}

from itertools import chain
import collections
super_dict = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in chain(A.items(), B.items()):
    super_dict[k].update(v)
super_dict
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A={'a':{"total":5,"all":[100,101]},'b':{"total":10,"all":[200,201]}}
B={'a':{"q1":"a","q2":"aa"},'b':{"q1":"b"},'c':{"q1":"c","q2":"ccc"}}

d = {}

for key in set(A.keys() + B.keys()):
    try:
        d.setdefault(key,{}).update(A[key])        
    except KeyError:
        pass

    try:
        d.setdefault(key,{}).update(B[key])          
    except KeyError:
        pass

print d
```

**output:**

```
{'a': {'q1': 'a', 'q2': 'aa', 'all': [100, 101], 'total': 5}, 'c': {'q1': 'c', 'q2': 'ccc'}, 'b': {'q1': 'b', 'all': [200, 201], 'total': 10}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A={'a':{"total":5,"all":[100,101]},'b':{"total":10,"all":[200,201]}}  
B={'a':{"q1":"a","q2":"aa"},'b':{"q1":"b"},'c':{"q1":"c","q2":"ccc"}}

C = {}

C['a'] = {**A['a'], **B['a']}  
C['b'] = {**A['b'], **B['b']}  
C['c'] = {**B['c']}

print(C)
```

> Result of print(C) using latest version of Python -- C being your
>   super_dict.
>   {'a': {'all': [100, 101], 'q1': 'a', 'q2': 'aa', 'total': 5},
>   'b': {'all': [200, 201], 'q1': 'b', 'total': 10},
>   'c': {'q1': 'c', 'q2': 'ccc'}}